# Расположение текста в Android Studio отличается от расположения текста на устройстве

Tags: java

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Файл MainActivity.java:

```
package test;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  private TextView mHelloTextView;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mHelloTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

  }

  public void onClick(View view) {
    mHelloTextView.setText("Clicked on");
  }
}
```

Файл activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  tools:context="test.MainActivity"
  android:clickable="false">

  <ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
    android:src="@drawable/germany"
    android:onClick="onClick" />

  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="@string/greeting"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_marginTop="55dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

P.S. текст `Hello, i'm ikerya` находится на той же позиции, что и `Clicked on`.

P.S P.S. Девайс: Lenovo A6010, 5 дюймов, Lollipop 5.0.2

Comment: Добавьте ещё и разметку в вопрос. А вообще полагаться на средства студии в случае с разметкой не стоит - там всё плохо, т.к. нужен полноценный девайс для учёта всех нюансов конкретной разметки.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб сделал

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё дело в длине текста и ширине TextView и его выравнивании по правому краю вышележащего виджета.

В студии у вас текст длиннее и не заметно, что его контейнер справа ограничен правым краем вышележащего элемента.

Скорее всего то, что вам нужно можно сделать с помощью `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"`, коий заменит `layout_alignRight` и `layout_alignEnd`:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="@string/greeting"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="55dp" />
```

Comment: работает, спасибо http://vk.cc/5iEZdU :)